# ar() function vs lag variables in lm()

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, autoregressive-models

I am trying to understand how the `ar()` function of the "stats" package differs from simply using lag variables in a regular linear regression through the Base `lm()` function.

I have ran:

```
ar(lh)
```

Which returned:

> Coefficients:
>        1        2        3
>   0.6534  -0.0636  -0.2269

So I assume this means the recommended model is AR(3). If my understanding is correct, this means that the data is well explained with a lag1, lag2 and lag3 on the dependent variable (as a way to replicate the AR(3) structure). So I ran the following code:

```
summary(lm(x~lag(x)+lag(x,2)+lag(x,3),data=as.data.frame(lh)))
```

Which returned:
[image: summary]

But the lag2 and lag3 are not statistically significant at all. I understand that ar() is not designed for you to find optimal parameters in an OLS regression, but I thought that the idea was roughly the same. So what do I missunderstand about AR?

Comment: According to `?ar`, the number of lags is chosen based on the `AIC. You can check this by running AR(1), AR(2), AR(3), and AR(4) using `lm` and then checking the AIC of each.

Comment: Also note that the method of default method of fitting for `ar` is not OLS.

Comment: Still, how can the OLS results be so different from the default method of ar?

Comment: They look pretty similar to me. AR coefficients are 0.6534 -0.0636 -0.2269 and OLS is 0.6578 -0.0658 -0.2348.

Comment: Yeah, the coefficients are almost the same, but they are not statistically significant (very high p-values). So why would ar() recommend to include three lags if they are so bad estimators?

Answer (score 0):

It's a balance between predictive power and overparametrization. These are respectively represented in the Akaike Information Criterion as terms corresponding to the loglikelihood and the number of parameters. So going from AR(1) to AR(3) you get an increase in predictive power that more than offsets the increased risk of overparametrization induced by adding two more parameters to the model. It doesn't look at statistical significance at all.